# Scope of `using namespace` in Unnamed Namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-directives

Why is the using directive `using namespace std;` in *when enclosed in an anonymous namespace* behaves as if it appeared at global scope?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace x
{
  using namespace std;
  void g()
  {
    cout << 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  cout << 1; // compiles fine if `namespace x` is replaced with `namespace`
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An unnamed namespace is equivalent to essentially writing:

```
namespace __compiler_generated_unique {

}
using namespace __compiler_generated_unique;
```

So it's like having a using directive at global scope. And using directives are transitive.

---

For a normative reference, here it is from n4861 (The C++20 standard draft):

> **[namespace.unnamed]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.unnamed#1) An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced
> by
>
> ```
> inline namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
> using namespace unique ;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```
>
> where inline appears if and only if it appears in the
> unnamed-namespace-definition and all occurrences of `unique` in a
> translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this
> identifier differs from all other identifiers in the translation unit.
> The optional attribute-specifier-seq in the
> unnamed-namespace-definition appertains to `unique`.

> **[namespace.udir]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.udir#4.sentence-1) For unqualified lookup ([basic.lookup.unqual]), the using-directive is transitive: if a scope contains a using-directive that nominates a second namespace that itself contains using-directives, the effect is as if the using-directives from the second namespace also appeared in the first.